# how to exract text between specific tags in html with php and regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have searched in stackoverflow for my answer but can't find anything.

my question is how can I extract specific text between specific tags and if the first word of text find inside tag it grab it until the end

here is my code

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.time.com/');
$homepage=htmlentities($homepage);
echo $homepage;
```

for example it give me this output

```
<div>
<span class="12334d">first text in url</span>
<span id="asdasd2">second text in url</span> <br />
<span class="ddie8">third text in url</span>
<span>something else in url</span> <br/>
<span>special thing is here</span>
<span>something else in web</span>
</div>
```

so I want to grab "**something else in url**" and "**something else in web**" with regex when it find first word "**something**" grab text until the end between ... and put it in string.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
[^>]*something[^<]*
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mohoj1/1)

Comment: tnx.it worked for me so how can I grab start with "something" or "special"

Comment: sorry and finally i want to know how to match everything but "text" or "special"